# Showing code only on Front Page "Posts Page"

Tags: conditional-tags

I have some code that I would only like to be displayed on the sidebar when on the blog (the page that displays the posts).

Now I am using this code...

```
<?php if(is_page('37')) { ?> 
...Show code...
<?php } ?>
```

The strange thing is if I enter any other page ID, it works as expected and shows the code, however, when I enter ID 37 (blog page), the code does not show on the blog page. Do I need to do something differently as it is my main post page and not a regular page?

*P.S By Post page, I mean the page I have set in the wordpress admin where posts should be displayed.*

[image: wp-admin reading settings]

Comment: Got it! Turns out I should be using is_home which seems to work.

Comment: Adam, is the screenshot correct? Also, answer your own Question (and mark it as the correct one in a couple of days), so it doesn't remain in the Unanswered list. Would be nice if you added a summary from here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Main_Page

Comment: yep will do. Yes the screenshot is correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Turns out I should be using `is_home` which seems to work.

More info here.. http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Main_Page